Include a local gradle library by another library
In android's gradle build system, is it possible that a library imports another library from a local file path?
I know that it's possible to add local gradle libraries in the root project by adding it to the settings.gradle. What I am looking for is to have a "settings.gradle for my library" where other local projects can be referenced in and included in my library.
So its
app
|
v
MyLibrary
|
v
A local android library imported by a path

The local library could have a "complex" build system, using libraries on their own, doing external native builds with c++ etc. I know that its possible to include a jar file as library for example, however, if possible I want to avoid using a packaged format for the library to include, so that the user can still modify all source files in the final android project.

This is not recommended approach you should avoid relying on local file paths for other libraries. They should support standard dependency management mechanisms or package their dependencies within themselves.


They should support standard dependency management mechanisms


To which ones are you referring exactly?


They already have check this link https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library
